# How to write condition for locator is present in the page using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am looking for the condition in cypress to verify and click locator is present or not.
If element is present go to condition and click on the element else leave and continue with the execution. Below code i have tried,

```
    cy.get(".paginationPanel.ng-star-inserted").then(($test)=> {
    if($test.text().includes('Show:')){
        //do something
    }else{

    }
})
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to success. Can anyone please help me.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or what are you looking for in your expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code works, what is wrong?

What do you want to click? The "Show" dropdown would be

```js
cy.get(".paginationPanel").then(($panel) => {

  if($panel.text().includes('Show:')) {

    cy.contains('label', 'Show').prev().click()  // click the Show dropdown

  } else {
    
  }
})
```

Comment: Fody, by passing {force:true} is able to click , I was missed in my code